# A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type. In 1 to Many relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework, fluent

I have to 2 simple classes as following:

PermissionGroup:

```
public class PermissionGroup
    {
        public int PermissionGroupId { get; set; }
        public string PermissionGroupName { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Permission> Permissons { get; set; }
    }
```

Permission:

```
public class Permission
{
    public int PermissionId { get; set; }
    public string PermissionName { get; set; }
    public int PermissionGroupId { get; set; }
    public PermissionGroup PermissionGroup { get; set; }
}
```

and the DataContext class:

```
public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    public DataContext() : base("name=con"){ }
    public DbSet<PermissionGroup> PermissionGroups { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Permission> Permissions { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Permission>().HasRequired(p => p.PermissionGroup).WithMany(f => f.Permissons).HasForeignKey(fk=>fk.PermissionGroupId);
    }
}
```

I made the configuration exactly like from [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh134698.aspx). But still I get the circular reference error which only got when dealing with self referencing object and not in this kind of **one to many relationships**.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: If I disable lazy loading by removing `virtual` keyword then it works but that is not a solution I think.

Comment: It also works if I remove the Navigation property but again not a real solution I guess.

Comment: Where do you get this error?

Comment: In case you are trying to serialize the data into JSON (for a JSONResult in an MVC project) format use [ScriptIgnore] attribute on top of the PermissionGroup property of Permission(child) class, which will stop the recursive loop. In your case it's like this:                        [ScriptIgnore]                                                                                    public PermissionGroup PermissionGroup { get; set; }